Woocommerce Subscriptions Cart table: add line of text before recurring totals
I would like to edit the table on the cart page, containing the total (sign in fee) and recurring costs for my subscription service. The current table looks like this below:

I would like to add a row with a line with text after the first 'Totaal' and before the first 'Subtotaal'. This text can be 'Recurring costs'.
I located the (as far as I know, I am new with this) the template php for the cart. I found it here: Woocommerce/Templates/Cart/cart-totals.php. I edited this template by adding the following line after the class 'order-total'. Unfortunately this did not work. I am in the dark as to why. Is the code wrong, or am I using the wrong template to edit this table? Help would greatly be appreciated!
<!-- Add your custom row here -->
        <tr class="recurring-totals">
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring costs', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>

The full code is pasted below:
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

?>
<div class="cart_totals <?php echo ( WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) ? 'calculated_shipping' : ''; ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' ); ?>

    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Cart totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon, false ) ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php elseif ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) ) : ?>

            <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php
        if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = '';

            if ( WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) {
                /* translators: %s location. */
                $estimated_text = sprintf( ' <small>' . esc_html__( '(estimated for %s)', 'woocommerce' ) . '</small>', WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] );
            }

            if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                    ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ) . $estimated_text; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></th>
                        <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->label ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) . $estimated_text; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        
        <!-- Add your custom row here -->
        <tr class="recurring-totals">
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Overzicht Subscriptie', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </table>

    <div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' ); ?>

</div>


For WooCommerce subscriptions, there are specific templates located inside the related plugin folder within "vendor" > "woocommerce" > "subscriptions-core" > "templates" > "cart"…
